# How to get info about db rowId on a ListView when opening a context menu on it?

Tags: android, listview

I've a ListView, builded. 
The listView as a row layour with the fiels _id, name, other from SQLite via a simpleCutomAdapter

I've an activity to create rows on db, and the list activity is working wel..

Now I want to add a context menu to delete a spceific row.

I've succesfully created a context menu with one entry (delete).

I know that when user long-tap on a row, Android triggers

```
onCreateContextMenu(ContextMenu menu, View v, ContextMenuInfo menuInfo)
```

My answer is: what's the best strategy to read the id from the listview row long-tapped and then keep 'in mind' to delete it from db when/if user tap 'delete' ?

I know how to delete a row from db, no problem on it. My question is all about how to read the id from a text view of the longtapped row of a listview.

I'm starting right now programming so I prefer doesn't implement a custom adapter just now. 
I'm looking to some things to just retrieve the info...

An idea: the list is build via a simplecustomadapter... is there a way to using the 'v' variable to access to the data row and read the id ? (like ... v.cursorLine.data._id ... :)

thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just use:

```
myTextview.getId();
```

or in example:

```
Integer myInt = myTextview.getId();
```

I hope that's what ware you looking for.

You can assign a TAG to a TextView and then get it in a string.

```
String myString = myTextview.getTag();
```